# Azure App Service Push Notifications Xamarin Forms iOS

Tags: azure, xamarin, push-notification

I followed the steps here for enabling push notifications in my Xamarin iOS app:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-push/

In the "Create a provisioning profile for the app" section, step 4, there is no certificate shown, even though I just created one

Comment: Did you create a distribution certificate or development certificate? Is you created a distribution cert, you need to create a distribution provisioning profile. The other way around for development. That could be why you aren't seeing anything in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Step 4 you need to provide Apple Development Certificate. This is a certificate required by Apple to identify you as a Developer. Creation of this certificate is not explained in the tutorial link in the question. 
This is the first certificate to be created.  [Here is Xamarin's documentation on how to create Apple Development  Certificate.](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/#Generate_a_Development_Certificate_Manually)

After creating this,  certificate will appear in that tab
You can verify the certificate by checking keychain.  After you generate the certificate,  and install it,  it will appear in your keychain as below

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  The steps to create a certificate are included in the Azure documentation.  They are the same as the ones described in the Xamarin documentation.  I created a certificate and an App ID, but still no certificate shows in the provisioning steps

Comment: Please check my edit,  to verify the certificate generated

Comment: Ahh!  I see now.  "In the Select certificates screen, select your development certificate used for code signing, and click Continue. This is a signing certificate, not the push certificate you just created."  Thank you!